# Posting <div> into Blogger default commenting system

Tags: blogger, comments

How do I post HTML code like `<div>` into a default Blogger commenting system?

Comment: but how i can show <div> tag there? is there any way?

Comment: @rakibtg - Please register your Stack Overflow and Web Applications accounts using the same OpenID. When you do the accounts will be associated and you'll regain ownership of the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add a `<div>` tag in Blogger comments.  As far as I know, only the following tags are supported in comments on Blogger:

```
<br> <em> <strong> <b> <i> <a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes only some of the html tags can be used and if you really wanna ad  you can do it by editing the whole template , I mean Html and CSS Sheet ! But try to keep the original backup with you before you start editing